# Why is my button taking me to the top of the page and why does it only allow me to click the very left edge?

Tags: html, jquery, css

My button is not working. I can only click the far left side and it takes me to the top of the page which I don't want. Also, My jquery is not working.

```css
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 44%;
  width: 58%;
  margin-top: -5%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 80%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 59%;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 130%;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ffaf1a;
}

#navbar-nav {
  position: fixed;
}

div ul {
  line-height: 390px
}

div ul li {
  width: 1%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

li {
  margin-right: -80px;
}

.nav-item-logo {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: -190px;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-top: 350%;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 200px !important;
  min-height: 250px !important;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-top: 86px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.poem-1,
.poem-2,
.poem-3 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 6px groove black;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#p-poem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Navbar start -->
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-3 mb-2">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item-logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="thinking-monkey-poetry-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo, a thinking monkey with glasses on"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--start of jumbotron-->
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4"> Next Level Workouts</h1>
    <p class="lead">Powerful pumps, Mental Motivation, and Explosive Endurance</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of jumbotron-->

<br><br><br>

<div class="poem-1">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p id="p-poem">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="poem-2">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p id="p-poem">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="poem-3">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p id="p-poem">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: your html code has numerous errors.  Use w3 validator service to see the errors and correct them

Comment: you can't specify same `ID` to multiple items.